# my AlarmService go off for only 3 sec

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer, android-pendingintent

i'm using alarm manger to set and alarm that's go off in exact time in day using service 
but it only run the mediaplayer for 3 sec and terminate the service ,
if i swipe the app while alarm song is running the service terminate

// when i used TimePicker instead of setting time by myself the alarm goes off immediately for 3 sec then stops and in the exact time that i picked using TimePicker the alarm works perfectly

```
<manifest

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
 <service
            android:name=".Service"
            android:exported="false" />
```

service

```
   public class Service extends android.app.Service {

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.rev);
            mediaPlayer.start();

            return START_STICKY;
        }
}
```

MainActivity

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2018);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 2);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 24);
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 4);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        setAlarm(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
}
 private void setAlarm(long time) {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, Service.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int ALARM_TYPE = AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(ALARM_TYPE, time, pendingIntent);
        else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            am.setExact(ALARM_TYPE, time, pendingIntent);
        else
            am.set(ALARM_TYPE, time, pendingIntent);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm is set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start the service as a foreground service with `startForeground(<notification id>, <notification>)` in your `onStart()` method. Then it will have higher priority and is less likely to be killed. See [startForeground](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html?hl=ko#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29).